# How to fix android SDK file not found

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-tools

can someone please help me cause i've been trying to fix this problem for hours now

> [flutter doctor picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAUMU.png)
> [SDK tools picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z736c.png)

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 
   10.0.22000.318], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 
    version 33.0.0)
✗ Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\huawei 
   d15\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-33\android.jar.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 
    17.1.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set this way also : `flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>` .Here your path is c:\AndroidSDK

once done close command prompt and reopen and run commnad again : `flutter doctor -v`

Answer (score 1):

Go to SDK manager on Android Studio.

```
File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools
```

Select and Install Android SDK Platform-Tools.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to android studio -> open settings ->search sdk
copy path.

[image]

add sdk path to environment variables in windows.